# Obtain a SymmetricReduction of a bivariate (symmetric) function given in Piecewise form

Tags: functions, polynomials, piecewise

I would like to re-express the following bivariate (symmetric) function 
(defined over the unit square)

```
f[x, y] = Piecewise[{{p1, 0 < y < x < 1}, {p2, y == x}, {p3, 0 < x < y < 1}}]
```

where

```
p1 = -(x - 1)^3 (x (x + 3) - 5 y^2 + 1); p3 = -(y - 1)^3 (-5 x^2 + y (y + 3) + 1);
p2 = p3 /. y -> x;
```

as a (bivariate) polynomial in the two symmetric polynomials, `s1 = x + y` and `s2 = x y`.

Can the `SymmetricReduction` command be applied to such a problem (involving a function defined in `Piecewise` form)?

Comment: Why not apply `SymmetricReduction[]` to `p1` and `p3` before feeding 'em to `Piecewise[]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks! I did try what J. M. suggested. No apparent simplification, however.

Comment: Thanks! I did try what J.M. suggested. No apparent simplification, however. I simply want to obtain a bivariate polynomial in s1 and s2 in "standard" form. That is, without the use of the Piecewise command. Something like "s1^3 +s1 s2 +s2^2.....", by way of illustration.